# Difficulties getting proceeds from a lawsuit from one's own lawyer after the case is over

Tags: lawyer, professional-ethics

Yes, I have a friend that has supposable won her case and is waiting for her money. the problem she is having is the Lawyer contract she sign has it where her Lawyer can make all decision without her knowledge, and she does not get informed or asked till after decisions are made. So she has been waiting for her payout for over 10 years now as the lawyer keeps deciding things for her like having to take more than one money class, and such after she has told her lawyer that she need her money now for living and more importantly for her medical she is now handicapped. she was to get money this Friday but again the lawyer has it delayed even though she was told by Judge there would be no more delays. How can she make it stop and get her money.

Comment: Hire another lawyer.

Comment: Unfortunately this will be closed since this site doesn't offer specific legal advice.  But, it sounds like your friend may be taken advantage of and she is going to need some professional help to resolve this.

Comment: She has had 3 lawyers first did this so she got out from under him second one wanted more money then the 3rd one the Judge helped her get and he is doing same thing first one was doing. I am just asking what she need to do to get control back you do not need to be specific but pointed in the right direction.

Comment: No one can really provide reliable guidance without a lot more detail about the case and the circumstances surrounding your friend's inability to get this money. From what I'm hearing, it sort of sounds like we're dealing with (1) someone who has been ruled incompetent; or (2) money that is in a trust or otherwise not intended for your friend's direct control. In either case, it sounds like the answer is to hire a good lawyer; your friend should not be surprised if a good lawyer wants more money than a lawyer who is going to screw her.

Comment: More specific what I know of it is. She and her husband purchase house and land lived there for 5 or 6 years the Sheriff comes and says they had to leave so they sued the County for double selling the same piece of land and they won.

Comment: The first lawyer was trying to force her to use friends for her winning from accountant to real-estate and she kept saying no and he kept making it take longer for her to get money so she finally got second lawyer.

Comment: The second one first agreed to a certain amount then changed his mind and wanted more when she said no he kept making her wait for money. Now 3rd lawyer I do not know why but is doing the same thing saying she has got to talk to a professional so that she is not taking advantage of with how much money she is getting.

Comment: My personal stake in this is  my Mom is renting her a house and they agreement between them is my mom would let her stay without paying rent thinking the money is going to come, I advised my mom not to do this but now it has been 10 years and still no money it is always money coming on this day then ether on that day or right before it has been delayed again and the money is suppose to be at the bank.